# Google url shortener: How to get back shortened url without any api limit?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-url-shortener

I want to use google url shortener api. I read that there is a limit of 1 or 10 per IP per second.

I want to hit it by C# console application. I would fetch long url from database and send them to google url shortening api. I will have to do 60000 times in a day.

How do i do this without getting any api limit exceeded error?

Comment: Where did you read that there is a limit of 1 or 10 per IP per second? According to [Google developers URL Shortener page](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#quota) you can do 1,000,000 requests per day. I did not find anything about X requests per second.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/limits-quotas#general_api

Comment: If you're doing this from a console app and assuming you have a foreach loop I would keep it simple and do a `Thread.Sleep(1000);` after your call to the api. That keeps it at 1 per second.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But i was thinking if there could be any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It would appear that the default for the URL shortener API is 100 requests a second If you really want to test hitting it why not just click the little pencil in the google developers console and set it to 1 per second.  Either that or you are going to have to run your console application a lot faster to hit it.

**Note:** Linking the quota for the [Google analytics MCF API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/limits-quotas#general_api) isn't going to give you any information on the URL shortener api.  You need to look at the documentation for the [API](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#quota) you are accessing each API has a different quota.